# SQL Update with variable for an equation

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I would like to ask how to **simplify the following prepared statement**, so it would use only 2, instead of 3 question marks (?), as for each 'sytosc + ?' I am setting the same value.

```
PreparedStatement psUp = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE zawodnicy "
    + "SET sytosc = CASE WHEN (sytosc + ? > 100) THEN 100 ELSE sytosc + ? END "
    + "WHERE id=?");
```

I know in SQL you can do:

```
SET @a = 25; 
UPDATE zawodnicy SET sytosc = CASE WHEN (sytosc + @a > 100) 
THEN 100 ELSE sytosc + @a END WHERE id = 1
```

Obviously you cannot put it into this prepared statement since these effectively are two statements.

**I wonder if there is actually a way to assign a local variable in this sort of SQL Update on first evaluation of the 'sytosc + ?'?**

I would greatly appreciate a solution compatible with MySQL as that is what I am using in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE zawodnicy SET sytosc = LEAST( 100, sytosc + ? )
WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was after. I accept it as it fits my particular problem perfectly. I just wonder, is there a solution (other then @JB Nizet gives) for a more complex situation, where you refer to the same value all over a query?

Comment: I can't think of any universal solution right now, sometimes queries can be just simplified to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Spring's [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html), and use a query like the following:

```
UPDATE zawodnicy SET sytosc = 
CASE WHEN (sytosc + :offset > 100) 
     THEN 100 
     ELSE sytosc + :offset 
END 
WHERE id = :id
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html for the documentation of Spring'sJDBC support, which has other advantages.

Comment: Thanks for this, +1 for that. Do you also know a Spring independent solution?

Comment: No. But you may use this class without having to use IOC and everything else that Spring provides.

Comment: Thanks again, this is very interesting class indeed. It might be of use in future for more complex situations. For now I will go with @piotrm 's answer, as it is perfect for my simple situation.